# 4104 error with linked server and aliased table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I am trying to write a query that uses a local database and a linked server and am getting a 4101 multi-part identifier error when I alias the linked server.

If I run

```
select *
from [ServerName\Instance].[DatabaseName].[dbo].[tbl_CUA_Visitation_Report_Line]
```

I get all of the table's records back. But if I run

```
select l.*
from [ServerName\Instance].[DatabaseName].[dbo].[tbl_CUA_Visitation_Report_Line] AS l
```

If get the message:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The multi-part identifier
>   "tbl_CUA_Visitation_Report_Line.acct_trip_end_date" could not be
>   bound.

I'll get the same when joining a local and linked tables using alias. This field is present in the table.

I cannot figure out what the problem is or where the issue might be.
Any help would be great.

Both databases are 2008 R2 (one is on SP2 the other SP1).

Comment: Does your SQL Server have CU5 applied?

Comment: Any view or trigger involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft confirmed this is a known bug. You have to install a cumulative update according to this link:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2352413/en-us?sd=rss&spid=13165

Comment: Downloading the hotfix but will take some time; does it need applied to both systems?